# modal close after submit using Thymeleaf spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have problem, when i click button submit the modal closed, what i can do id when i click the submite button modal will still open?

When i click submit i want to reload exist modal form.
Code form is in fragment/header  when i click the button "login" modal shows
The problem is in views/loginForm i have the same code modal but this 
requires button open modal but I do not want to , i want refresh exist modal , or immediately open the same model on another page.

```
 <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#demoModal" href="/login">Logowanie</a>
```

Modal:

```
 <div class=" modal" id="demoModal" data-backdrop="static" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title ">Please confirm!</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger col-12" th:if="${param.error}">
                <h2 class="">Invalid Email or Password</h2>
            </div>
            <form  th:action="@{login}" method="post">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="form-control-label">Email</label> 
                        <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control" 
                                    id="email" name="username"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password" class="form-control-label">Password</label> 
                        <input type="password" 
                                class="form-control"
                                id="password" name="password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" >Zalogj sie</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

On the @GetMapping

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String showLoginForm() {
    return "views/loginForm";
}
```

[photo-logi-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqnQE.png)

when he enters the wrong password, he dispatches to:

http://localhost:8080/login?error

however, he closes my modal

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're returning the view that displays a modal again.
What you want to do is to implement some login logic to redirect to another view which doesn't contain modal (or contains closed modal):

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login() {
    if(isSuccessfulLogin) {
        return "redirect:/loginSuccessPage";
    }
    return "views/loginForm";
}
```

Comment: When i click submit i want to reload exist modal form.